# JQuery Very simple POST not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to simply POST something using JQuery. when the element is clicked, I want the page redirect to the php file and echo out the POST value.

Html file

```
  <html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="posttest();" >hi there</div>
<script>

function posttest(){
var txt="hi";
$.post("testpost.php", {testVar: txt},function(){
    window.location.href = "testpostphp.php";
});
}
</script>
</html>
```

PHP file

```
<?php
var_dump($POST["testVar"]);
?>
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: You don't understand difference between ajax and page reloading.

Comment: How are you storing this variable at server? If you aren't how do you expect this to work?

Answer (score 0):

1. There is `$_POST` variables in PHP, not `$POST`.
2. Try this:

   ```
   $.post("testpost.php", {testVar: txt}, function(response){
       console.log(response);
   });
   ```